# Heavy load produces possible memory leak in netty when using ejb-remoting in wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly

We have two wildfly 16 server running on Linux. First with JDK 11.0.2, second with JDK 8.
Wildfly 1 has a remote outbound connection to wildfly 2 which is used for HTTP-remoting. This is necessary because it has to run with Java 8 32 bit.
When we perform a load test after 100.000 requests from wildfly 1 to wildfly 2 response time increases steadily.
A heap dump analysis of wildfly 2 using MAT gives us some information about the problem. The heap dump shows a lot of ‘io.netty.buffer.Poolchunks’ that use about 73% of the memory. 
Seems the inbound buffers won't be cleaned properly.
Wildfly 2 does not recover when the load stops.
Is there any workaround or setting to avoid this?

Comment: Have you solved this? Could you share your solution, please?

Comment: I switched to REST calls to avoid it.